# LIKE clause using wildcard with multi value parameter

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm stuck in this problem for days. In "report builder" I made my report having parameters: `@ProductGroup` and `@RBS`.

`@ProductGroup` has some specific values (chosen from checkbox).

`@RBS` has two fields: 1. MemberValue  2. MemberFullValue.

`@RBS` gets values from a query using the selected value from `@ProductGroup`. I use LIKE clause with wildcards. The query looks like:

```
    SELECT MemberValue, CAST(MemberFullValue AS Varchar(2000)) AS MFV
    FROM MSPLT_RBS_UserView
    WHERE (CAST(MemberFullValue AS Varchar(2000)) LIKE '%' + @ProductGroup + '%')
    ORDER BY MFV
```

The problem is: it works well if i select single value from `@ProductGroup`, but when I select multi value it shows nothing.

I also tried `IN` clause. Doesn't work.

Comment: If you have multivalue your string comparison will look like `LIKE '%1,2,4,6%'`which means you get a comma separated list. If you use `IN` you lack the wildcard `%`.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I want something like: LIKE '%' + Parameter1 + '%' OR LIKE '%' + Parameter2 + '%'.....

Comment: I think you will need to parse the parameter string and build a dynamic sql query around it. Not that i recommend that, i think you should think about redesigning your report and/or query. You can also try to use subreports in a tablix, just an idea.